# Inserting a id value into a <a> tag?

Tags: php, html

i wanted to input a id value into a  tag, where the value is hidden but i want to pass that value to another page . I have the code for input type however i have no idea how to do it on a  tag.

codes for input type:

```
<input type='hidden' name='id' value='$id'/>
<input type='submit' value='More details' />
```

how to archieve the same effect on  tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to pass information in a link (an `<a>` tag) besides putting it in the URL.

Comment: Guess i can only create multiple page instead of passing information to one page. Thanks alot guuys

Answer (score 0):

You can put an onclick event on the specific  tag that changes the hidden input fields value. e.g.

```
<a href='#' onclick="setHidVal('1');">Test</a>

function setHidVal(idVal)
{
  $(function(){ $('#myHiddenField').val(idVal); }); //You don't have to use jquery
}
```

So once posted, you can request the hidden field name to get value.

Answer (score 0):

what is the problem? any value of a form`s input, even in a hidden input you find in

```
$_POST[id]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can append in a tag like this.
**Method 1:**

```
<a href="your-page.ext?id=<? echo $id; ?>">
```

**Method 2:**

```
<form name="hidden_form">
<input type='hidden' name='id' value='$id'/>
</form>
<a href="your-page.ext" onclick="javascript:return submit_frm(this)" > some thing goes here</a>
<script>
function submit_frm(aelem) {
   document.hidden_form.action = aelem.href;
   document.hidden_form.submit();
   return false;
}
</script>
```